# Can't Connect Orderer and Peer Nodes on Different Machines on AWS

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to build a network with a single orderer and 3 organizations, each organization with a single peer node on AWS with Hyperledger Fabric Version 2. I can successfully generate the genesis block for orderer and channel configuration transaction using configtxgen with following commands:

`configtxgen -profile ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID ordererchannel -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block`

`configtxgen -profile ChannelAll -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/channel.tx -channelID channelall`

Here is my configtx.yaml file: (The policies here are not a good practice, just experimenting)

```
---
Organizations:

- &OrdererOrg
    Name: OrdererOrg
    ID: OrdererMSP
    MSPDir: ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

    Policies:
      Readers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
      Writers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
      Admins:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"

- &Org1
    Name: Org1MSP
    ID: Org1MSP
    MSPDir: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

    Policies:
      Readers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
      Writers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
      Admins:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
      Endorsement:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"

- &Org2
    Name: Org2MSP
    ID: Org2MSP
    MSPDir: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

    Policies:
      Readers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
      Writers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
      Admins:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"
      Endorsement:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.member')"

- &Org3
    Name: Org3MSP
    ID: Org3MSP
    MSPDir: ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

    Policies:
      Readers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.member')"
      Writers:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.member')"
      Admins:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.member')"
      Endorsement:
          Type: Signature
          Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.member')"

Capabilities:

Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    V1_3: true

Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V1_1: true

Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V2_0: true
    V1_3: false
    V1_2: false
    V1_1: false

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

Organizations:

Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    LifecycleEndorsement:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Endorsement:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

OrdererType: solo
Addresses:
    - orderer.example.com:7050
BatchTimeout: 2s
BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 300
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
Kafka:
    Brokers:
        - 127.0.0.1:9092
Organizations:

Policies:
  Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
  Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
  Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

  BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults

Policies:

    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"

    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"

    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:

ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
        Capabilities:
            <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3
ChannelAll:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
            - *Org3
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

When I join `peer1` to the channel I create, I get the following warning in my orderer's docker logs:

`Handle -> WARN 008 Error reading from 172.31.19.174:35362: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled`

At first, I just ignored this warning and joined the other nodes to the channel. However, I wasn't able to connect to the blockchain with my client program which makes use Fabric Node SDK, so I believe this is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: are you using docker swarm on was ?

Comment: I am not, I'm using extra_hosts in my docker-compose file. For example:
peer0.org1.example.com:

    extra_hosts:
            - "orderer.example.com:172.31.95.122"
            - "peer0.org2.example.com:172.31.20.132"
            - "peer0.org3.example.com:172.31.22.56"

Comment: Have tried to ping your container, is it reachable ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the specific port with nmap, it says open

Comment: nmap you have used from local or aws instance  ?

Comment: Both, result is PORT:7051/tcp, STATE:open, SERVICE:unknown

Comment: security groups are configured with all tcp 7051 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199671/discussion-between-flopoe-and-mohammed-rampurawala).

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you use

`configtxgen -profile OneOrgOrdererGenesis`

while in your `configtx.yaml` in Profile section is `ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis`.

Maybe you should try to generate crypto files with following commands:

`configtxgen -profile ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID ordererchannel -outputBlock ./config/genesis.block`

`configtxgen -profile ChannelAll -outputCreateChannelTx ./config/channel.tx -channelID channelall`

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy & paste error. I was running the correct command. I was able to run my network successfully even though I got that warning. It's probably because of my other peers haven't joined the network at that point, so gossiping wasn't working properly.